# In systemd how would I get how long the last job took to run?

Tags: linux, systemd

When I look for systemd job timing I get a lot of docks about timers which isn't what I'm looking for. How would I time the length of execution of a `systemctl start xyz` job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the time command.

In your case:

```
time systemctl start xyz
```

Comment: I don't believe this works. For long running commands, it will return immediately. Status will show it is actively running as background process. Probably I have to do some `jounalctl -u xyz.service` but I don't know what command to get the timing on the last run

Comment: It works under _systemd's_ definition of a "job" (where a job may be e.g. "start unit xyz.service"), your definition is just different from that.